# Adding Pictures/Symbols with Hyperlink in a Document Library

Tags: 2010, document, library, hyperlink, picture

Is there any EASY option to add **Pictures + Hyperlinks** to a **Document Library**? Like on the front page where you just click on

> "edit" > "insert" > "Picture" > "insert" > "Hyperlink"

I googled it already and all I read is something with **HTML-codewriting** and stuff like this... which if of course a good Option if you are used to it, but I never used HTML or SharePoint before - i am doing an internship and my Supervisor asked me to find out how to make our **SharePoint** better.

If there is no easy way let me know please

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 or O365?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SharePoint 2013 (or newer) or O365, I'd suggest to create a custom link list which can be placed at the Document Library's (view) page. The list should be based on **Promoted Links** app which is available out-of-the-box.

On your SharePoint site go to Site Contents > add an app > Promoted Links. Name as you like. Create new list items to your Promoted Links -list and remember to specify the *Background Image Location* with the URL to the picture you wish to have for your link.

Once you have your links ready, on your SharePoint site go to Site Contents > Document Library you'd like to place the links > Edit page. On the web part zone, click *Add a Web Part* and choose your Promoted Links -list. You can choose whether to show/hide the list's title from the web part properties.

A working example:

[image: A working example]

Limitations:

- Promoted links come with a fixed size of 150x150px
- Promoted links do not have line breaks meaning if you have 8 links, they'll all be in the same row. A workaround for this is to have two or more Promoted Link -lists placed above the Document Library's view page.

The limitations can be altered with frontent customization, but that'll require some extra work.

Comment: Thanks for you quick and very detailed answer! Its actually SharePoint 2010, but I still gonna try what you have explained! :)

Comment: I think Promoted Links doesn't exist in SharePoint 2010. There's a nice guide for how to achieve similar with Content Query wp: https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/content-query-web-part-and-links-navigation-solution-promoted-links-alternative/